# How to get the user key pressed while inside a loop in native/pure JS?

Tags: javascript

I have no idea how to perform a "getch()-like" function in Javascript while inside a loop.
Here is my running code and I want to add a user interface based on what he presses:

```
SNK.moveSnk = function(){
        (function myLoop(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                        SNK.ctx.fillRect(SNK.x,SNK.y,10,10);
                        switch(SNK.mD){
                                case 1:
                                        SNK.y-=11;
                                        if(SNK.y>=1) myLoop();
                                        break;
                                case 2:
                                        SNK.y+=11;
                                        if(SNK.y<=496) myLoop();
                                        break;
                                case 3:
                                        SNK.x-=11;
                                        if(SNK.x>=1) myLoop();
                                        break;
                                case 4:
                                        SNK.x+=11;
                                        if(SNK.x<=551) myLoop();
                                        break;
                        }
                },100);
        })();
}
```

the `SNK.mD` should be changed based on the keyboard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onkeypress` event, then check for the character introduced and take the required action. Exmample:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    console.log("Key pressed code: " + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the window listener 'keypress'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.which